# In versions of JS upto and including ES6 are there any mechanisms available for the generation of sequences without loops or recursion?

Tags: javascript, sequences

In versions of JS upto and including ES6 are there any mechanisms available for the generation of sequences without loops or recursion?

For example:

```
[n, n*2...] // Hypothetical syntax that I know to be invalid JavaScript
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"I am trying to find out if there is a shorthand for this kind of operation in the language"* What kind of operation? Printing a list of consecutive numbers? That's quite a specific application IMO and does not seem to  require a syntax extension or API extension.

Comment: `for(var x=0; x < 100; x++) { console.log(x); }` **is** shorter. What are you really asking for a shorthand for? Array comprehensions?

Comment: I guess the numbers are a sequence, so my question would be better put - are there any built-in sequence handling functions in ES6?

Comment: @apsillers: You are way too verbose: `for(var x=0;x<100;x++)console.log(x);` :P

Comment: @Ben: So something like `range` in Python? No there is not afaik.

Comment: I found this post http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/07/sequences-using-javascript-array.html

Comment: If you refer to array comprehension, that was deferred to ES7.

Comment: @FelixKling interestingly that post also provides examples using only `Array`, `apply` and `map`. But I take your point

Comment: Either way, `Array`, `apply` and `map` already exist in ES5. You really should edit your question to reflect your actual intentions.

Answer (score 0):

No there are no operators built-in to the language specifically for generating sequences, but you can re-purpose some existing methods for sequence generation.

For example:

```
[...Array(5)].map((x, y) => y*2); // Array [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```